# How to replace multiple same lines in notepad++ without doing it manually?

Tags: replace, notepad++, multiline

Hi I need to replace in notepad++ 30 lines with new ones already copied, so each line gets replaced line by line.

These lines should be replaced:

5, 13, 21, 29, 37, 45, 53, 61, 69, 77, 85, 93, 101, 109, 117, 125, 133, 141, 149, 157, 165, 173, 181, 189, 197, 205, 213, 221, 229, 237

Example:

```
(5th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABC
(13th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCD
(21th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE1
(29th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDEF2
(37th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDEFGH
(45th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE11
(53th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE23
(61th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE452
(69th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE526
(77th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE631
(85th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE516
(93th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE747
(101th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE642
(109th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE644
(117th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE6243
(125th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE6447
(133th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE6723
(141th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE7433
(149th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE62672
(157th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE62346
(165th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE75384
(173th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE8532
(181th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE67355
(189th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE734575
(197th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE73455345
(205th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE6734534
(213th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE634537
(221th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE74577
(229th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE43423
(237th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktestABCDE5623623
```

And now while having all 30 new lines already copied, each line has to be replaced line by line.

So that's the effect after replacement:

```
(5th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest11a1
(13th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest22a1
(21th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest33a1
(29th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest44a1
(37th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest55a1
(45th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest66a1
(53th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest77a1
(61th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest88a1
(69th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest99a1
(77th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest111a1
(85th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest222a2
(93th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest333a3
(101th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest444a4
(109th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest555a5
(117th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest666a6
(125th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest777a7
(133th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest888a8
(141th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest999a9
(149th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest1111a1
(157th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest2222a2
(165th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest3333a3
(173th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest4444a4
(181th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest5555a5
(189th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest6666a6
(197th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest7777a7
(205th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest8888a8
(213th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest9999a9
(221th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest11111a1
(229th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest22222a2
(237th line) https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest33333a3
```

Of course ---> (X line) is just an explanation where these lines are located , it should look like this after:

```
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest11a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest22a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest33a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest44a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest55a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest66a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest77a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest88a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest99a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest111a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest222a2
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest333a3
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest444a4
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest555a5
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest666a6
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest777a7
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest888a8
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest999a9
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest1111a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest2222a2
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest3333a3
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest4444a4
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest5555a5
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest6666a6
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest7777a7
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest8888a8
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest9999a9
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest11111a1
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest22222a2
https://signin.gg.com/p/web2/examplelinktest33333a3
```

Thank you for any tips concerning this.

Comment: The easiest would probably be to write a script in a language like Python that opens the original file and the file with the replacement lines and selectively writes lines to a new file from either the original or the replacement based on line number.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.